# use searializer field in template Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to `Django Rest Framework` and writing first API application.

my **contacts/models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'contacts'

    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name()


class ContactEmail(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'contact_emails'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**contacts/searializers.py**

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    primary_email = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('url', 'full_name', 'date_of_birth', 'primary_email')

    def get_primary_email(self, obj):
        primary_email = obj.contactemail_set.filter(primary=True).first()

        if primary_email:
            return primary_email.email

        return ''
```

**contacts/views.py**

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user)

class ContactList(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'contacts/list.html'
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Contact.objects.all()
        return Response({'contacts': queryset})
```

Where `ContactViewSet` is accessible by `http://<ip>:<port>/api/contacts` and `ContactList` is accessible by `http://<ip>:<port>/contacts`

`http://<ip>:<port>/api/contacts` is giving **primary_email** in the json response but it prints nothing on using in **list.html** `{{ contact.primary_email }}`

**Can't I use Serializer fields when using **APIView**?**

**Do I need to rewrite the function in the `ContactList()` to get primary_email field?**

> Edit 2: `contacts/list.html`

```
{% for contact in contacts %}
    <h4 class="card-title">{{ contact.full_name }}</h4>
    <h5>{{ contact.primary_email }}
    <a href="{% url 'contact:detail' contact.pk %}">Click here</a>
{% endfor %}
```

This is printing user's full name but not primary email

Comment: Is it possible to see `contacts/list.html`?

Comment: see `Edit 2`. Added `contacts/list.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the serializer in `APIView` to have access to its fields. You also need to use Django `render` helper passing the contacts in the context in order to render the template since `APIView` has no knowledge about rendering custom templates.

One option is to serialize data before adding it to context in your ContactList. Something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


class ContactList(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'contacts/list.html'
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get(self, request):
        serialized_contacts = ContactSerializer(
            Contact.objects.all(), many=True).data
        context = {'contacts': serialized_contacts}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

But I don't see a reason for using APIView or serializers in that view. What I would do:

1. Add a `primary_email` property to the `Contact` model:

   ```
   class Contact(models.Model):
       user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
       date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

       class Meta:
           db_table = 'contacts'

       @property
       def full_name(self):
           return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

       @property
       def primary_email(self):
           primary_email = self.contactemail_set.filter(primary=True).first()

           if primary_email:
               return primary_email.email

           return ''

       def __str__(self):
           return self.full_name
   ```
2. With this new model, it wouldn't be necessary to have the `get_primary_email` method defined in `ContactSerializer`:

   ```
   class ContactSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
       primary_email = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

       class Meta:
           model = Contact
           fields = ('url', 'full_name', 'date_of_birth', 'primary_email')
   ```
3. Instead of using `APIView` for the `ContactList` view, I'd use Django's generics.ListView.

   ```
   from django.views.generic import ListView
   from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


   class ContactList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
       template_name = 'contacts/list.html'
       permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
       queryset = Contact.objects.all()
   ```

Comment: Yes, I have added function to the model class and it is easy to use from both `APIView` and `API` but still I need answer to the question as there could be many functions which I can't write in model directly. Your answer will come handy at that moment.